# Official Android app comment controls are not intuitive

Tags: bug, android-app

Version 1.0.48, Android OS 4.2.1

The recent changes in comment handling have been not entirely helpful.

First, the comment tool bar appears far away from where the comments are.
Novice users cannot notice it easily.

https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html

> **To display actions and, if necessary, the action overflow, use the bottom bar.**

I understand this may be a CAB (Contextual action bar), but it is still too far to be noticed.

https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html#contextual

> What else is important enough to warrant continuous display?
>
> **Sometimes it is important to display contextual information for your app that's always visible.**

Second, there are no indications on what each of the icons does. Vote Up is the easiest, Reply To non-intuitive, and the Checkmark at the left entirely puzzling. Besides, the arrows in the Reply-To and Vote-up icons are of different widths.

(EDIT #2): **Turns out the reply button [image] originates from the [official icon pack](https://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html). The upvote button doesn't.**

(EDIT) The action bar's background brown color is not pretty.

[image: Sample]

BTW, many thanks for the Reply-To feature.

Suggestions:

- co-locate actions with the comments as per the official dev guide
- replace the UpVote icon with the official pack's rating good button [image: good rating]
- if possible add some text captions
- remove the checkmark

Comment: Changing the up vote arrow to something like `▲` or similar? Sure. But a thumbs up goes against all convention on the actual sites and I think it will confuse more users than help.

Comment: @StevenV - agreed. A fat triangle doesn't compete with the reply-to shape.

Comment: I actually have no idea why your top bar is brown, it's supposed to be a shade of dark blue. Are you running any customization on your phone?

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi - no customization, it's a pleasure to deal with responsive developers. Thanks for a great app!

Comment: @DeerHunter hmm... what device are you running? It might be a manufacturer skin that's causing that, if I can see it happening on one of my devices I can fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some general feedback:

Thank you so much for the detailed feedback! It's honestly amazing to see someone put the effort into it to actually look up the design documents to see why we're doing what we're doing :)

As far as I can tell, we have no control over the checkmark on the left. We don't draw that ourselves, the Android OS takes care of setting that up. The only thing our code does is the actual actions on the right (plus the ones in the overflow menu).

The thumbs-up button from the official pack really doesn't match the rest of our UI. If I added it in I guarantee that we'd get another meta post the next day saying "Why is this a thumbs up? It's an arrow everywhere else". We originally tried using a triangle icon from the action bar (the "collapse" icon) but that was not very easily understood by users, so I switched it to an up arrow to make it more obvious. We could change it to an arrowhead like on the websites, which would work out since it could also match the width of the reply icon, but I don't know if the widths of all of the other icons (if you look at it on a tablet the items in the overflow menu show up as actual icons) match either.

Regarding adding text to the action bar: I'd really rather not. You don't see this anywhere else on Android because it makes the small bar seem *really* cluttered. Normally it's either text, or an icon, never both. However, all Android action bar buttons automatically have a nice feature to help discoverability (ironically, this feature itself is not quite discoverable): If you long-press on any of the icons you'll get a floating text that says what tapping it does. This works in every app since it's an OS native feature.

I don't quite understand what you mean by co-locate, do you mean moving it to a secondary action bar on the bottom of the page? I'm very much so in agreement with that (trying to access the top action bar on a >5" device is torture, which is one of my big complaints about Android as a platform) sadly we're not able to do that at the moment due to bugs with what happens to our presentation if that is set up. However, I'm currently in the middle of a huge rewrite of the question/answer view in the Android application and changing the comment contextual action bar to be in the bottom should work very easily after my rewrite is done.

I'll update this answer post the Q&A rewrite and go through which parts of this [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) and which parts of this are [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined). Thank you *so* much for the awesome in-depth post :)

Answer (score 3):

Since I can't comment, I'll have to write an answer.

What someone else doesn't find intuitive, someone else does. From what I recall, anyways, is that most "action bars" float at the top on Android, unlike iOS and Windows Phone where they sit at the bottom. With my experience of Android, apps would annoy me no end that tried to bend conventions and make their own UIs.

"change the icons" is not much a helpful comment either. That's like those comments saying "Needs fixing and updating". Fix what? Change what?

"add some text captions" isn't going to work -- where on earth would you put those captions? Remember that not everyone has a HD Android device.

All in all, this isn't exactly a bug.

Comment: Thanks, will update with refs to Android Dev Guide.

Comment: You can comment, here on MSE "comment everywhere" is granted at 1 rep: http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment